# How do you convert a dynamic range into a table using Excel Scripts?

Tags: excel, power-automate, office-scripts

I am new to using excel scripts with power automate. Trying to convert some data to a table. The thing is the number of rows will differ each time.

I've done this in excel desktop, but not sure how to do it using an excel script.

Comment: Please update this question with a specific example of an input and desired output.

Comment: Please add your excel desktop example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is finding the used range in excel(Office Scripts). Once you have it, i assume you know how to convert it to table.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) 
{
  // Get the current, active worksheet.
  let currentWorksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();

  // Get the range containing all the cells with data or formatting.
  let usedRange = currentWorksheet.getUsedRange();

  // Log the range's address to the console.
  console.log(usedRange.getAddress());
}
```

[Link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwikg8SzlJv0AhVVVisKHX4lBXcQFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fjavascript%2Fapi%2Foffice-scripts%2Fexcelscript%2Fexcelscript.range&usg=AOvVaw3SduQUKHjtIpkRBVV9emkI) for your reference

Answer (score 0):

From:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/excel-samples

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Get the current worksheet.
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();

  // Create a table with the used cells.
  let usedRange = selectedSheet.getUsedRange();
  let newTable = selectedSheet.addTable(usedRange, true);

  // Sort the table using the first column.
  newTable.getSort().apply([{ key: 0, ascending: true }]);
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31244205)

Comment: The script included is the answer, link was for reference